# Django runserver not serving static files in development

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, static-files

I am using Django with `runserver` for my development. When I deploy to my production server I can see all my static files, but not on my local computer.

I did `collectstatic` and I have set `DEBUG = True`.

I found many different opinions online, the most prominent being the `STATICFILES_DIRS`, but that does not work for me.

How can I set it so that in my development environment I can see the static files, and when I upload my files to the server I do not need to make any changes for the production environment to work properly.

Edit - my `urls.py` file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
import newsflashes
import settings

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('newsflashes.urls')),
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Edit - file structure:

I have two directories, static and dynamic. Inside static are the static files, and in the dynamic directory are the django apps.

Edit - Settings:

My relevant settings are as follows

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
```

Comment: Have you [followed the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) and added the appropriate lines to your `urls.py`

Comment: Yes, I added the urls file to the question

Comment: You should tell us something about your settings (STATIC_ROOT, STATIC_URL, STATICFILES_DIRS) and static files location

Comment: Added to the question above. Should I add anything else?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I managed to fix it.

I created another directory in my project folder called static and copied my static files there.

I then added:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
import settings
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

to my `urls.py`

and

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

to my `settings.py`.

Then, when I deploy I execute `manage.py collectstatic` and since Apache is configured properly, everything will work!

Based on http://dlo.me/archives/2013/01/14/how-to-serve-static-files-django/

Thanks to all.

Comment: To clarify, in settings.py make sure DEBUG is set to true, then in urls.py add the urls.py code above.

Comment: I only had to point STATICFILES_DIRS to my (source) static file dirs. After that, running collectstatic collected the files, and after that runserver would serve them. Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: This has already been included by default in the [`django.contrib.staticfiles.urls`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/staticfiles/urls.py)

Answer (score 11):

I usually run `python manage.py runserver --insecure` to force serving of static files with the staticfiles app even if the DEBUG setting is False.

Here's the link of their documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#cmdoption-runserver-insecure

Comment: Thanks, I am sorry about that, I have deleted and upvoted