# Django CRM module not showing the Navigation Menu bar correctly

Tags: django

I am installing Django CRM from Micropyramid. I was able to compile and run the server successfully, however, the navigation menu is not showing correctly. Attaching screen shot.

Thanks
With Regards

Ganesh. S

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGHDn.png)

Comment: this is becouse of the static files follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/20400751/7887883

Comment: Tried the above mentioned steps, however it is not working. Getting the same issue.

Comment: did you check developer console in browser to verify static files are loading or not